# Get TruncatedSVD.transform() to return float16 instead of float64

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am using Sci-kit Learn's `TruncatedSVD` algorithm to perform LSA on a sparse matrix.  I want the transformed dense matrix to have data type `float16` instead of `float64`.  Note: I don't want to change the data type AFTER the transformation - my computer would be out of memory by then.  I want `TruncatedSVD.fit()` to directly return something of type `float16` - how can I do that?

I tried changing my original sparse matrix and `TruncatedSVD.components_` to `float16` before applying the transformation, but the output data type is `float32` only - an improvement, but not quite what I want.

Comment: Do you mean `fit` or `transform`?

I think Bitwise's answer is correct. If you manage to get it working for you, you might want to consider submitting a pull request to add a `dtype` argument to control the `TruncatedSVD` precision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking in the code, `TruncatedSVD` uses `as_float_array()` from `sklearn.utils`. The code for `as_float_array()` is [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/utils/validation.py).

As you see, the documentation states that

> The new dtype will be np.float32 or np.float64

I guess you can hack it to be float16 (perhaps remove the use of `as_float_array` altogether?), but I am not sure what the consequences would be.

One thing that you should consider is that using larger variables (e.g. float64) in these kinds of numerical algorithms helps with the numerical stability. This is especially important if you are dealing with a very large matrix. If you will use float16 you might be risking getting incorrect results due to numerical issues.